# How do you navigate to a new page/route using a ListTile in Flutter?

Tags: flutter

Within Flutter, I am trying to navigate to a new page when I press on a ListTile widget. I am trying to use the ontap() function, however it doesnt appear to be working.

```
ListTile(
                leading: Icon(Icons.border_color),
                title: Text('Freelance English Native needed'),
                subtitle: Text('Requirements: Native English'),
                onTap: () {
                  Navigator.pushNamed(context, '/second');
                },
              ),

MaterialApp(
  // Start the app with the "/" named route. In this case, the app starts
  // on the FirstScreen widget.
  initialRoute: '/',
  routes: {
    // When navigating to the "/" route, build the FirstScreen widget.
    '/': (context) => MyApp(),
    // When navigating to the "/second" route, build the SecondScreen widget.
    '/second': (context) => SecondScreen(),
  },
);
```

Comment: what error does it show in your logs/debug console

Comment: share your error also.

Comment: can you check if the onTap function is called by adding a print statement in onTap callback?

Comment: I added a print statement, and it returned correctly in the console.
When I run the code from my question, I get the error here:

════════ Exception caught by gesture ═══════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════
The following assertion was thrown while handling a gesture:
Navigator operation requested with a context that does not include a Navigator.

Comment: Also, it returns this:

Handler: "onTap"
Recognizer: TapGestureRecognizer#5afd5
  debugOwner: GestureDetector
  state: ready
  won arena
  finalPosition: Offset(210.3, 220.3)
  finalLocalPosition: Offset(210.3, 24.3)
  button: 1
  sent tap down

Comment: Instead Navigator.PushNamed, try using "Navigator.(context,MaterialPageRoute((context) => SecondScreen));

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
ListTile(
                leading: Icon(Icons.border_color),
                title: Text('Freelance English Native needed'),
                subtitle: Text('Requirements: Native English'),
                onTap: () {
                 Navigator.push(
                   context,
                    MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => SecondScreen()),
        );
                },
              ),
```